# How to set up Octave 3.8

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I know getting Octave 3.6.2 is simply done by `sudo apt-get install octave` however for the matlab file I am trying to run requires Octave 3.8. The only help installing it that I've seen shows how to install it to Ubuntu. Has any tried to/sucessfully installed Octave 3.8 to Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Just curious about: why your script is requiring octave 3.8? Which functionality?

Comment: Ive been using ocatve 3.8 installed from source, and it is still buggy. oh look a debian package: https://packages.debian.org/sid/octave

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if Debian has added Octave 3.8 in a release, probably the last one. If so, you must add the corresponding repository in you source file `/etc/apt/source.list` and retrieve the corresponding key (`wget`). Then you update your application cache (`apt-cache update`) and install it (`apt-get install`) as usual.

If there is some incompatibilities with Raspian distribution or there is no compiled repositories yet available, you will have to compile it by yourself targeting your Pi. You will find octave source on their [ftp](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/). This step is not that easy because octave rely on many dependencies.

If you fail in those steps, you may reconsider your script design in order meet Octave 3.6 standards or wait for Debian release including Octave 3.8.

As I said above I am really interesting to know what function you need in 3.8 and, by the way, I am sure you are aware about that, your Pi is not the best target to execute Octave script because of its lack of resources.

**Update 1:** Octave 3.8 is available in Debian Jessie and Sid (alpha version). You may try to add one of those repositories and install Octave through this way. Notice that it may require other packages update and then you might experiences some troubles. [Octave for Debian (All Release)](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=octave)

If you succeed to install, do not forget to edit your question by answering it completely in order meet SE standards and help other users.